# Magento Site - Card Skimming

Tags: magento-1.9

So it looks like one of our sites is targeted by card skimming when you select a payment method a new iframe is loaded which asks the users for their card details.

It quite clever in the fact if you try to load the console it disappears.

Has anyone come across something like this, could you point me in the right direction of where to start fixing the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I've come across this before

Check the field Miscellaneous Scripts from

System->Configuration->Design->Head

Here scripts will be added before the  tag and you can set different scripts per website or even store views.

Check different store scopes. Check for white space before to mask existence.

Once removed don't forget to clear your Magento cache: System > Cache Management > Flush Magento Cache

Also be aware that this could have been inserted via code. Doesnt necessarily mean your admin URL and username password is known.

If not there could be in static block which appears on checkout like in a footer.

Comment: Yep, found it was in a static block in the footer!

Comment: Good work. If you are happy with the answer please mark as correct.